# What is a Null value for a Long variable type in a Windows API call?

Tags: vb6, windows-api-code-pack

Stupid question. I think this should be 0, but I can't seem to find it.

So, if I want to pass a Null value to a Windows API call (this happens to be in VB6), what value would I use?
I think 0, but I guess it could be VBNull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the API argument is a `LONG` (and not, say, an `LPVOID`), try passing the zero long integer literal `0&`.

Answer (score 1):

Often this would be a *null pointer* and not a null value.

Then it depends on the Declare syntax actually used.  If the declared argument was a `ByRef ... As ...` item then you'd say `ByVal 0&` (or sometimes `vbNullString`) in your call.

However if you declared pointers as `ByVal ... As Long` in the declaration (for use with `VarPtr()`, `StrPtr()`, etc.) simply using `0&` in the call is what you want.